# iOS Background Execution even app not in background or foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to develop the feature in my app. A background program will run where it attempts to upload the pictures every 5 minutes for 2 hours until all the pictures taken have been uploaded. So is it possible to upload pictures even app is not in background or foreground. I have some idea of [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Can you please let us know your thoughts?

Thanks in advance for support.